# Array of enum is switched to Array of enum member in typescript mapped type

Tags: typescript, mapped-types

I'm currently trying to create a mapped type that creates the angular form group type from a given model type.

I've created a mapped type that checks if a given property is an array and then creates a mapped property of the type `FormArray<T>`. The problem is that arrays of enums are not mapped correctly.

For a property with the type `MyEnum[]` i get the resolved type `MyEnum.A[] | MyEnum.B[]` so i can't add different values of the enum to the array.

Here is a slimed down version with the same problem:

```js
enum Environment{
  "EN" = "en",
  "US" = "us",
}

interface MyDto {
  environments: Environment[];
}

export type FormControlsOf<T> = {
  // Check if the property is an array
  [TPropertyKey in keyof T]-?: T[TPropertyKey] extends Array<infer TArray>
  // I check whether TArray is a record so i can decide whether this should be a FormControl or FormGroup in the real code
  ? TArray extends Record<any, any> ?
    // we ignore records for this example
    never 
    // We map to property to an array; here we use the simple array type but the real code would 
    // map this to FormArray<FormControl<TArray>>
    : TArray[]
  // we ignore non arrays for this example
  : never;  
}

const q: FormControlsOf<MyDto> = {
  environments: [Environment.EN, Environment.US]
  // The type of environments is actually (Environment.EN[] | Environment.US[])
};

// Error:  Type 'Environment[]' is not assignable to type 'Environment.EN[] | Environment.US[]'.
//  Type 'Environment[]' is not assignable to type 'Environment.EN[]'.
//    Type 'Environment' is not assignable to type 'Environment.EN'.
//      Type 'Environment.US' is not assignable to type 'Environment.EN'.(2322)
// input.tsx(8, 3): The expected type comes from property 'environments' which is declared here on type 'FormControlsOf<MyDto>'
```

Source: [typescriptlang.org](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAUwdgrgtgBAomAbgSwE4HsxXAFwN7AwwBEcAcsTALwnjEA0hJAqgMqU3EQDODwAvsGDIwOEKgBmAQwDGIGAFkAngBEc6GASLgUGLLm4AueEjSZsogNoBdANwChIAB4AHdKhwwcSl-IBi7lAAwpg4GAA23ADyEgA8ACoAfNSaTAD0aTBBABYgMgDWMMgSXrkwLhi+HkpF3DBSYPWoqFJKTJbxAAqV4t4A0iA1IjD5g+gl8dYAtAD8xvEd3ehV-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-k1TwpG4bh1TAKQcRjd0-3kGjTzorCkPWNDaMw7CbCo+8iMyCj-wEjDzykpj0BYtiOK4niND46jxPPR8yCkmTlSbeJKMU4DcEYw1mPqDSNS08MdIs-TELIaTZKbMzXMEiS2Bsuo7NY9jHO45z4wUtz33IaSYIAJgAZni+L8OVEQXGTe8LycGCAA5pUS3D5jKZxfBkMRQV0jNsAHDBYAqZZehqKigIQ0RuEY95kCef5YRkcI-RAUEg3JRkLI3Gst2iOI93URIqKAA)

If i remove the check on `TArray` in line 13, the type of `environments` is correctly detected as `Environment[]` but i need the check to decide whether this property is a `FormArray<FormGroup>` or `FormArray<FormControl>`.

Edit: @wonderflame and @Robby Cornelissen were correct that Distributive Conditional Types were the problem.

Here is the full code for the angular form group mapped type:

```
/**
 * This mapped type allows to create types that represent the form group representation of that type.
 *
 * Example:
 * interface MyDto {
 *    prop1: string;
 *    prop2: string[];
 * }
 *
 * FormGroupOf<MyDto> will become:
 * {
 *    prop1: FormControl<string>;
 *    prop2: FormArray<FormControl<string>>;
 * }
 *
 * This allows to define fields that are fully typed.
 *
 * class TestClass {
 *
 *    public form: FormGroupOf<MyDto>;
 *
 *    constructor() : {
 *      this.form = new FormGroup({
 *        prop1: new FormControl(""),
 *        prop2: new FormArray<FormControl<string>>([]),
 *      })
 *    }
 * }
 *
 * Doing it this way allows code completion in both, the template and during the cunstruction of the formgroup.
 *
 * For complex property types this works recursively.
 * interface MyDto2 {
 *    prop1: {
 *      innerProp: string;
 *    };
 * }
 *
 * FormGroupOf<MyDto2> will become:
 * {
 *    prop1: FormGroup<{
 *      innerProp: FormControl<string|null>;
 *    }>;
 * }
 */
export type FormGroupOf<T> = FormGroup<FormControlsOf<T>>;

export type FormControlsOf<T> = {
  [TPropertyKey in keyof T]-?: T[TPropertyKey] extends
    | (infer TArray)[]
    | undefined
    ? [TArray] extends [string | number | boolean | undefined]
      ? FormArray<FormControl<TArray>>
      : FormArray<FormGroupOf<TArray>>
    : T[TPropertyKey] extends string | number | boolean | undefined
    ? FormControl<T[TPropertyKey] | null>
    : FormGroupOf<T[TPropertyKey]>;
};
```

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/m3vAkN) work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; If not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to prevent the default [distributive](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) behavior of the conditional type:

```
export type FormControlsOf<T> = {
  [TPropertyKey in keyof T]-?: T[TPropertyKey] extends Array<infer TArray>
    ? [TArray] extends [Record<any, any>] // <- Prevent distributivity
      ?　never 
      : TArray[]
    : never;  
}
```

---

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAoiBuBLATgexBUAXA3gKCigCIYA5IqAXmNCIBoDiBVAZQuqLAGd68BfPHkQgswZADMAhgGNgUALIBPACJZUUfIVBI0GbFwBcsBCnSYRAbQC6Abn6DgADwAOqZFihZFzuQDE3EADC6FhoADZcAPLiADwAKgB8VBqMFnEACmg+7ooA0sCKUMJQANYFqOJQcVYAtAD8RnFpmajZXvmKVlBOoiAAJlxQAILIyJKKMcLiYlUjY4oJjIR1UGlz4109oAOrAErA0m59MZIginRQpwtWS4RQdYAADCDA8DO3hI3rita3Rs+vyBshHseEOIC4HgAjkZ-MggiFwlFYkpVKgktRNN0TLpzFhDKs4DozNgAHRkC6E0x6EQk1g3Ph2IA)